# Gradle Builds with NanoHTTPD, but class cannot import

Tags: android-studio, gradle, nanohttpd

This is probably a really stupid question, but after messing with this for 2 hours, I cannot seem to resolve.

I am wanting to use nanohttpd in an android app as a lightweight local webserver. The gradle seems to find nanohttpd and builds just fine with the dependency; However, I cannot seem to include it in any of my java class files.

for example: I create a new class file and use: 
`import org.nanohttpd.protocols.http.response.Response;`

I get the following error:
`error: package org.nanohttpd.protocols.http.response does not exist`

It also does not detect org.nanohttpd.* or even org.*

Below is my Gradle dependency line from the app level Gradle.build:
`implementation group: 'org.nanohttpd', name: 'nanohttpd', version: '2.3.1'`

This identifies current version and seems to work.

And here is the full Project level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4'
        classpath "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.10"
        classpath "org.nanohttpd:nanohttpd:2.3.1"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you cannot import org.nanohttpd.

The correct syntax is:

`import fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD.*;`

Not sure if this is different from the nanohttpd github project...